# RailsかWordpressでのサイト運営について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

私は個人で事業を運営するためにサイトを作ろうと思っておりますが、RailsかWordPressのどちらかで制作しようか迷っております。

機能は、オンライン学習商材のように課金をしたら、テキスト商材や動画商材が閲覧でき疑問点があればチャットで対応できるようするつもりです。

Railsはプログラミングスクールに通いTwitterの簡易版のようなサイトは作れるレベル。
WordPressは一度も触ったことがないレベルです。

悩みは以下の3点があげられます。
・WordPressの方が管理がしやすいのではないか。
・WordPressの方がSEO対策がしっかりされているのではないか。
・WordPressの方がかなり素早く完成できるのではないか。

いずれもRailsをより勉強すれば解決できる問題だと思いますが、サービスをリリースするのに1年など長時間はかけたくありません。
もし上記をRailsでも素早くカバーできるなら、今後の幅が広がると思うので使っていきたいです。

いろいろなサイトを閲覧しましたが、両者を比較しているサイトが少なかったのでよく分かりません。
みなさんの意見をお聞かせください。

Comment: 率直な意見を述べさせていただきますと、上記のような条件ですとRailsの方が向いているとは思いますが技術を習得するにはもちろん時間がかかりますので何処かに依頼にするか、Udemyなどの既存の枠組みを利用するのがいいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

## 経費面で

railsとwordpressを比較する上で、実際に問題になるのは色々とあるとは思いますが、真っ先にあげるとすれば、サーバーの問題が挙げられます。

- wordpressはphpで出来ている為、大体のレンタルサーバーで動きますし、ワンクリックインストールできるレンタルサーバーが多いです。
- railsはrubyがベースで、アプリケーション・サーバーが必要です。
  herokuなどのPaasを利用する等、wordpressに比べて若干知識や、運営においての経験が必要となります。（学校で習ってるとは思いますが）

[railsのサーバーについては、　こちらを参照](http://www.sejuku.net/blog/7117)

その上で、問題になるのは経費の問題だと思います。　どのくらいの規模で、どの程度の人間が利用するかと、想定して上記のサーバーを運営する必要があるためです。

**スケールアウト**までを考慮していくとキリが無いですが、保守、運営も自身で行うのであれば規模やユーザーの同時接続数、利用者数等を考えおくのは必要かと思います。

## SEO対策として

- wordpressはseo対策プラグインは豊富です。ウェブアプリという形でなければ単純にウェブサイトとして運営するのであればCMSなので、入れたその日から運営が可能でしょう。（デザイン等こだわらなければ）
  ただ、SEO対策自体がどういう物かを知った上での、内部対策のみではなく、外部対策は必要になるかと思います。
- railsでももちろんSEO対策は可能ですし、何ならrailsで作られたCMSを利用するのも手かもしれません。ただ、それだと人が作った物を動かすわけで、カスタマイズや理解するための学習コストは物によるとは思います。

[rails cms　参照](http://webnokoto.com/ruby/ruby-on-rails-cms5)

seo対策については、どちらも最初の入り口はさほど敷居は高く無いとは思います。コンテンツ作りに没頭したいなら最初からCMSのwordpressでもrails謹製のcmsでも、さほどカスタマイズなどをしなくても、ある程度までは行けるかもしれません。
ただ自分のサイトに出来る内部対策以外の外部対策や、最終的な競合サイトに対するマーケティング、差別化など（本当はこれが最初に必要）を考えれば、どちらがどうとは言えない部分もあります。

## 技術面、学習コスト

ここからは時間やコストの話しになりますが、wordpressやrailsの既存のcmsを使えば、どちらでスタートさせても最初の数週間で出来る事はさほど差はないかもしれません。

> 機能は、オンライン学習商材のように課金をしたら、テキスト商材や動画商材が閲覧でき疑問点があればチャットで対応できるようするつもりです。

wordpressであれば上記のような機能は、もしかすると一つもプログラムを書かずにプラグインだけでデジタルコンテンツの販売を行える物もあります。

[ダウンロード販売サイトを簡単に作れるWordPressプラグイン](http://netaone.com/wp/easy-digital-downloads/)

もちろん、railsでもそういった事は可能です。ただ、やはりそこはプログラムをバリバリ買いたり、プラグインというよりはライブラリをガンガン利用していく必要は出てきますので、終盤にかけてはやはり習熟度での差がどうしても出てきます。なので最終結論として・・・

## 結論として

本来これを先に考えるべきとは思います

- wordpressはデザイナーベースに人がテンプレートを弄ってウェブサイトを作成したり、便利なプラグインを使ってサイト機能を充実させたりするのに適している。
- railsはプログラマーがウェブサイトよりはウェブサービス、アプリを作成するのに適している。

という側面があります。
そういう意味で言うとwordpressの方が最初の間口としては広いのかもしれません。
実際現場において、デザイナーでも、ある程度の知識があればwordpressのテンプレートを利用しながらプラグインで機能を追加して使用したりしています。

しかしデザイナーの方でrailsでバリバリサイトを構築する人間を少なくとも私の周りでは見た事はありません。長々と書きましたが、参考になれば幸いです。